# Project management software

Tags: project-management

We're a team of 2 persons (a programmer and a designer) working on a rather big project, actually several projects of varying complexity. I'd like to know if there are any particulary good project management tools to help us in our task. The requirements would be :

- Easy to use. We don't want spending too much time learning how it works. Something straightforward would be cool.
- Platform agnostic.
- **Not** web-based as we don't want to rely on an internet connection to get things done. The absolute perfect thing would be some app that would work offline and then syncs everything when we're online.

I hope such app exists, even if it's not free, we're willink to make an investment if its worth it.

Thank you :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Project tracking/management tool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60240/project-tracking-management-tool)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you try Microsoft project , based on what your saying it should fit your needs. I use it for my projects and a company that I work for uses it too.

Comment: Thanks, i'll have a look at it

Answer (score 2):

Latitude would be the ideal tool base on the specs you want. It can be used by two or more people. It's a project management tool that is NOT web-based. It runs on your desktop so that means it is faster and has more functionality than web-based. It's simple and straightforward to use. You can check more of its features in their website: http://www.latibiz.com/

Answer (score 0):

For two people, I think that software tools would be overkill. There are times when tools just get in the way of getting the job done, and I think that this is one of those times.

I would suggest using spreadsheets and word processors for time and task tracking and email (with appropriate tagging or foldering) for communication. If you are in the same place, whiteboards (or large pieces of Plexiglass) would would nicely.

Comment: We're 2 people but the projects (5) are rather big. Using just spreadsheets would quickly become ugly as we need to keep a very clear overview on what have been done, what needs to be done, time estimates, etc ...

Comment: If you use a spreadsheet with certain formatting guidelines, it can be made to work well. There are some project management templates out there if you search around.

Comment: I've often seen spreadsheets used where they really shouldn't be, but if you're not using the resource management capabilities of MSProject then it's really not much more than a glorified spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

I am not much aware about other project management software; however, I have been using Microsoft Project Professional 2010 from past eight months and haven't faced any problems. It is a perfect [enterprise project management software](http://www.microsoft.com/project/en/us/solutions.aspx), which is used across many companies since, it is very easy and simple to use.